# CLGeocodeCompletionHandler only has one placemark entry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geocoding, clgeocoder

The documentation for

```
- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

The documentation clearly states:

> In the case of forward-geocoding requests, multiple placemark objects
>   may be returned if the provided information yielded multiple possible
>   locations.

states that it returns an array of placemarks. However, even if I search for objects I know for certain have multiple entries (Hollywood, washington, Denmark, main street, ect.) i always only get one entry.

Some people just shrug and say use the google API instead, but i fear for the request limit.

Is there some setting or hack to fix this, or is the `CLGeocoder` simply broken ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely suggest using Google Geocoding API - it is simply superior. I also argue, that you should not fear the usage limit for Google Geocoding APIs requests.

If you are developing mobile application, I suggest implementing client-side geocoding - that means, that every device queries directly Google API. As it is directly stated in [Google's own documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat?hl=sk#client)

> geocoding limits are per user session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global limit as your userbase grows.

More info in [geocoding strategies docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat?hl=sk#client) and [geocoding docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Comment: Sounds like the way to go :)

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer to the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

MKLocalSearch is the answer here:

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "addressToBeSearched"
request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: span: )
let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

localSearch.start { response, error in
    // returns (MKLocalSearch.Response?, Error?) -> Void
    // which ultimately has an array of MKMapItem from which you can extract a placemark.
}
```

This returns the nearby and not only, points of interest, places, etc.
The only drawback I can think of is that you have to provide the current location in the initializer for MKCoordinateRegion and the span.